# How to set Projection in Google Calendar with Calendar.Builder

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

To access ExtendedProperties, I need to inform the full projection.
Every example I've seen, they do so by URL:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/reference#Event_feeds

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/userID/visibility/projection
```

But I do not have that URL. I create the service as follows:

```
Calendar createService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT).setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(EMAIL)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(FILE_NAME).getFile()))
                .build();

        Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                                       .setApplicationName("Rokko-Leggis")
                                       .build();
        return service;
    }
```

I tried to save and retrieve a ExtendedProperty but failed

How can I save a custom field?

Answer (score 1):

Found!

```
    ExtendedProperties extended = new ExtendedProperties();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("customField", "customValue");
    extended.setShared(map);
    event.setExtendedProperties(extended);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have done this with two lines less:

```
this.calendarEvent.setExtendedProperties(new ExtendedProperties().setShared(extendedPropertiesMap));
```